# What happens to pending tasks when GeoServer reboots?

Tags: geowebcache, geoserver-rest-api

I am running a GeoServer/GeoWebCache system on a Windows server. We do regular updates which require retiling and I have an automated system (using Task Scheduler) that sends requests to the GeoWebCache REST API. There are times when there can be thousands of requests generated and the retiling can take several hours or more.

My question is: What happens with the pending / currently executing tasks if GeoServer (or the main server) is rebooted?

Answer (score 1):

After some real world experience with this I can see that on rebooting the server or restarting Tomcat, GeoWebCache loses any current/pending tasks.